# mobile simulator - user agent and screen resolution dependent redirects

Tags: redirect, emulation, simulator

I would like to create mobile simulator ie like http://testiphone.com/. But what is important to me, I want it to show mobile website if it exist regardless of what kind of redirection is used. With user agent redirection it isn't so hard (cURL or simple PHP proxy), but how to deal with redirection dependent on screen resolution that is widely used as well?

Answer (score 0):

The best of my findings is using opera mini simulator: http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/ It's Java and I could embed it on my site